# FS.Store unreliable gm image conversion

Tags: javascript, meteor, imagemagick

The code below does work most of the time, but sometimes it produces zero byte images. I suspect it's the part of the stream where the image is scaled `.sample(...)`. Thanks for any help!

```
function scaleToTargetByInt (width) {
    var maxWidth = 216 * 2; // 2x thumbnail size optimized for Retina display
    var originalWidth = width;
    var scaleInt = Math.floor(maxWidth/originalWidth);
    var scaleSize = scaleInt * originalWidth;
    return scaleSize;
}

var OriginalsStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("OriginalPix", {
    path: pathToOriginalsFolder,

    transformWrite: function (fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {

        // read image dimensions and write to metadata
        gm(readStream)
        .size({bufferStream: true}, FS.Utility.safeCallback(function (err, size) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            } else {
                fileObj.update({$set: {'metadata.width': size.width, 'metadata.height': size.height}});
            }
        }))
        // read metadata.width and scale acordingly
        .sample(scaleToTargetByInt(fileObj.metadata.width))
        .stream()
        .pipe(writeStream);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var` keyword. 
and on the update, we should pass the `._id` from some document if not how mongo will now which document upload?

try with

```
fileObj.update({_id:this._id},{$set: {'metadata.width': size.width, 'metadata.height': size.height}});
```

or

```
fileObj.update({_id:fileObj._id},{$set: {'metadata.width': size.width, 'metadata.height': size.height}});
```

the code should look like this.

```
 OriginalsStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("OriginalPix", {
    path: pathToOriginalsFolder,

    transformWrite: function (fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {

        // read image dimensions and write to metadata
        gm(readStream)
        .size({bufferStream: true}, FS.Utility.safeCallback(function (err, size) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            } else {
                fileObj.update({_id:fileObj._id},{$set: {'metadata.width': size.width, 'metadata.height': size.height}});
            }
        }))
        // read metadata.width and scale acordingly
        .sample(scaleToTargetByInt(fileObj.metadata.width))
        .stream()
        .pipe(writeStream);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan, but the suggested changes (removing `var`, adding `{_id:fileObj._id}`) are not improving something. Using the original code I get this error `W20150204-00:00:15.775(-8)? (STDERR) stream.js:94
W20150204-00:00:15.775(-8)? (STDERR)       throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.`

Comment: make this please. `console.log(fileObj)` im pretty sure fileObj is undefined

Comment: Plus this `W20150204-00:00:15.776(-8)? (STDERR) Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/kai/eboydb/.meteor/local/cfs/files/_tempstore/MyPix-LEPFsPyjCs6H9Y5iy-0.chunk'`

Comment: also try with `$push` not with `$set`

Comment: I don't understand, why would it work sometimes then? @Ethaan

Comment: i think the problem is on the callback but im not sure

Comment: with $push the values are appended to an array. $set is working fine though. The problem is zero byte image files – sometimes, sometimes not. There is a problem with the stream I think.

Comment: Yes you are right – it might be the callback as well. :/